# Does Bazel support enumerating transitive dependencies, and dependency repository locations?

Tags: bazel

I am trying to find a way to list all dependencies, as well as dependencies of dependencies for a Bazel project, as well as listing any external repositories that are being fetched for them. Does Bazel support this functionality?

I have tried using the Bazel query samples in the documentation (https://docs.bazel.build/versions/0.27.0/query-how-to.html) to list dependencies, but it seems like these don't include any transitive dependencies. I also can't figure out a way to list repository information for fetching.

Comment: [No, not really.](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/external.html#transitive-dependencies) You can list all (include nested) dependencies in your parent `WORKSPACE` file. Or you can define function that you load and run directly (or over another hop) from your `WORKSPACE` file.

Comment: Workspace files aren't recursive right now, but once the workspace is setup up with transitive dependencies, I believe `query` should still list targets within those transitive dependencies that targets in your main repo depends on. How about something like `bazel query "deps(//...:all)"`? (maybe with a combination of `--keep_going`, `--nohost_deps`, `--noimplicit_deps`)